# Copy recursively by specifc folder and extension

Tags: linux, bash, macos, unix

I want to copy recursively from folders with a specific string contains in the name of the folder and a specific type.

```
./test/one/Print\{space} 100/ /* note: there is a space between Print an the number */
./test/one/Print\{space} 200/
./test/one/Internet\{space} 100/
./test/two/Print\{space} 100/
./test/two/Print\{space} 200/
./test/two/Internet\{space} 100/

./destinationfolder
```

Now I want to copy only files with jpg extension and those who are in the 'Print' folder.

How can I do this on a console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Bash's `globstar` feature to achieve this:

```
cd _your_directory
shopt -s globstar nullglob
cp **/Print*/*.jpg ./destinationdir
```

It works well for files or directories that have whitespaces in their name.

From Bash [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html):

> globstar
>
> If set, the pattern ‘**’ used in a filename expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
> If the pattern is followed by a ‘/’, only directories and subdirectories match.

Answer (score 1):

You can couple `GNU find` with some `bash` manipulation to achieve what you are trying to do,

```
find . -type d -name "Print*" -exec sh -c 'x=$1; cp -v "$x"/*.jpg ./destinationfolder/' sh {} \;
```

should do the trick for you. The idea is to use a glob pattern `Print*` to get the names of the folder containing `Print` and run a shell `-exec` to do copy of the files with extension `*.jpg` from the folder name `x` (here double-quoting of `"$x"` will prevent things from getting get ugly if name does *contain* spaces) and move it to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

When a folder name contains "spaces" you can use quotes so that it can be treated as a name wit spaces..

To copy *.jpg files from "print 200" directory, one can use 
              cp -Rp "print 200"/*.jpg destinationfolder/